# "Cats are of three types"

Tags: meaning, usage

Suppose there are three types of cats:

> Cats are *of three types.*

Is this good English?  The *to be of ... types* structure could be found on google though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not ungrammatical, but that doesn't mean there couldn't be a better way to say it. The best wording often depends on context.

If this was the opening sentence on a piece about cats, I might recommend this form:

> There are three types of cats: pedigree, cross-breed and non-pedigree.

However, if the sentence was buried more deeply in a paragraph, I might like your wording better:

> Of the many household pets a family may own, two of the most common are dogs and cats. Cats are of three types: pedigree, cross-breed and non-pedigree.

In that passage, I think the rewording helps the two sentences flow together in a natural way.

I'm not aware of any hard-and-fast rule that prescribes when one form should be used instead of the other. However, in a question that asks, "Is this good English?" – without much other context – the answer could well be that sometimes it's excellent English, and sometimes it's not.

Incidentally, I did an [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20of%20two%20types,there%20are%20two%20types%20of,%20are%20of%20three%20types,%20there%20are%20three%20types%20of,%20are%20of%20four%20types,%20there%20are%20four%20types%20of&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), and looked through some of the results. Indeed, it wasn't hard to find examples where the *"are of n types"* usages followed the form I alluded to, (that is, where *"are of n types"* follows a sentence where the word was mentioned previously):

> The inflectional paradigm consists of the process of reduplication affecting the theme and the **affixes**. These **affixes** are of two types: categorial affixes and incorporated forms.
>
> **Subjective ultimates** are the consciousnesses realizing emptiness and objecive ultimates are the objects of those consciousnesses. **Subjective ultimates** are of two types, actual and concordant.

Nor was it hard to find *"There are n types"* passages that were starting a new section of a book:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Once again, I'm not saying one form couldn't be used in place of other. I'm merely pointing out that **context might influence a preferred wording**. The O.P. didn't ask if one particular wording was "ungrammatical", but asked whether it was "good English."

Answer (score 3):

The structure 'to be...of types' is *absolutely* fine.

From [the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/may/01/gerry-adams-arrest-south-sinn-fein-republic-of-ireland)

> North of the border people who vote Sinn Féin **are of two types.** There are those who supported the IRA and believe the campaign was a good thing ... Then there are republican critics of Adams, who accuse him of selling out

From the [Business Standard](http://www.business-standard.com/article/opinion/unaided-effort-114050801398_1.html)

> Private schools **are of two types:** those that are aided by the government and those that are not.